Minimal set of prime ideals with intersection a certain ideal
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $I \subseteq R$ a radical ideal. Let $A = \{\mathfrak{p} \mid I \subseteq \mathfrak{p} \text{ and } \mathfrak{p} \text{ is prime}\}$. i.e. the set of all prime ideals containing $I$. Let $B = \mathcal{P}(A)$ be the set of all sets of prime ideals containing $I$. Let $C = \left\{D \in B \mid \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in D} \mathfrak{p} = I \right\}$ be the set of all sets of prime ideals containing $I$ whose intersection is actually $I$.
Must $(C, \subseteq)$ contain minimal elements?
I think this might be provable using Zorn's Lemma, but I can't get it to work. Here is my attempt:
First of all, we show that $C \neq \emptyset$. Indeed, since $I$ is radical, we have $I = \bigcap_{I \subseteq \mathfrak{p}} \mathfrak{p}$. Hence we have $A \in C$.
It remains to show that any chain in $C$ has a lower bound. Indeed, let $E \subseteq C$ be a chain in $C$. Let $F = \bigcap_{D \in E} D$. It is clear that $F$ is a lower bound for $E$. It remains to see that $F \in C$. By construction, $F \in B$. It remains to see that $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in F} \mathfrak{p} = I$. This is the part where I cannot continue the proof. I can only show that $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in F} \mathfrak{p} \supseteq I$.

Unfortunately, you cannot apply Zorn's lemma directly. For instance, consider $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $I = (0)$. The poset $C$ does have the minimal element $\{(0)\}$. However, it also has the chain:
$$\{(2), (3), (5), \ldots\} \supset \{(3), (5), (7), \ldots\} \supset \{(5), (7), (11), \ldots\} \supset \cdots$$
which has no upper bound since the intersection of all sets in the chain is empty.
Your claim is true for Noetherian rings since any radical ideal can be expressed as a finite intersection of prime ideals. However, it need not be true for general commutative rings. For example, consider the ring $R = \mathbb{C}[x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, \ldots]/(x_1y_1, x_2y_2, \ldots)$. The ideal $(0)$ is radical since it is the intersection of the minimal primes $(z_1, z_2, \ldots)$, where each $z_i \in \{x_i, y_i\}$.
However, $C$ has no minimal elements. Indeed, if $D \in C$ was a minimal element and $\mathfrak{p} \in D$, then: $$J = \bigcap_{\substack{\mathfrak{q} \in D \\ \mathfrak{q} \neq \mathfrak{p}}} \mathfrak{q} \neq 0$$
However, we have $J\mathfrak{p} \subseteq J \cap \mathfrak{p} = 0$. There exists a minimal prime $\mathfrak{p}' \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ and non-zero $f \in J$, so we also have $f\mathfrak{p}' = 0$. This would imply that $fz_n = 0$ for all $n$. However, this would imply that $f$ involves infinitely many variables, which is absurd.
ADDENDUM: Any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ must contain either $x_i$ or $y_i$ for each $i$ since $x_iy_i = 0$. Furthermore, each ideal of the form $(z_1, z_2, \ldots)$ with the above notation is prime since the resulting quotient is isomorphic to the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables. Thus, the ideals of the form $(z_1, z_2, \ldots)$ are precisely the minimal primes.

Thank you! Could you add a short addendum explaining why the minimal primes of your example are exactly of this form?
